# Trained Keras model is not working with custom images. What could be the cause of it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I have trained a model to classify different fruits and vegetables. I used Fruits-360 dataset from Kaggle-https://www.kaggle.com/moltean/fruits

The model's accuracy is 98%, and yes it predicts correctly every single image which I give it as input from test data-set. But the problem is when I give it a random fruit picture from internet or captured image from a phone it always predict it wrong. What is the cause of it and how to solve it?

Here is the python code:

```
  1       import cv2
          from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, save_model, load_model
          from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
          import numpy as np
          import pandas as pd
          import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
          from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
          from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
          import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
          import matplotlib.image as mpimg

  2       filepath = '../input/Models/my_model.h5'

  3       train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                       rescale=1./255,
                       shear_range=0.2,
                       zoom_range=0.2,
                       horizontal_flip=True)

          test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

          train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                     '../input/fruits/fruits-360/Training',
                      target_size=(100, 100),
                      batch_size=100,
                      class_mode='categorical')

          test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                     '../input/fruits/fruits-360/Test',
                     target_size=(100, 100),
                     batch_size=100,
                     class_mode='categorical')

  4       model = load_model(filepath, compile = True)

  5       input_image_path = '../input/real-images/20200720_125831.jpg'

  6       from PIL import Image
          import numpy as np
          from skimage import transform
          def load(filename):
             np_image = Image.open(filename)
             np_image = np.array(np_image).astype('float32')/255
             np_image = transform.resize(np_image, (100, 100, 3))
             np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image, axis=0)
             return np_image
  
  7       image = load(input_image_path)
          predictions=model.predict(image)
          img=mpimg.imread(input_image_path)
          imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
          plt.show()

          idx_to_name = {x:i for (x,i) in enumerate(train_generator.class_indices)}
          idx_to_name[np.argmax(predictions)]
```

Output when image for prediction is from test dataset and its right
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9plUJ.png

Output when image for prediction is taken randomly from internet you can see its wrong
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4s6N.png

Comment: you have used variable for image path as "input_image_path" and loaded image using variable just "path" and there is no variable "path"  in the given code. I got confused. can you make it clear for rme.

Comment: Ohh sorry it was my mistake during editing, path is  input_image_path. I cleared up the mistake BTW

Comment: I'm new to ML but I believe, just like Gerry P's answer, your model won't recognize images that aren't neatly cropped etc, as you can see in the dataset. I've been working with the same dataset and have come to the same results (which led me here). My approach to this is to either do transferred learning or choose a different dataset that contains a more diverse set of images such as fruits-262. Unfortunately, this one does not have train/test folders but I'm doing it myself manually and will post eventually on kaggle.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you pre=process the image by cropping your images so that to the maximum extent possible the region of interest (the fruit or vegetable) occupies the majority of the pixels in the image. Doing so makes the probability distribution of your randomly selected images closer to the distribution of the images the network was trained on. The idea  of training on images that have a lot of clutter is not a good one in my view. After all you want your network to focus on identifying fruits and vegetables not trying to process images with a lot of clutter. For example I do a lot of work with facial images. I purposely made a training, test and validation set in which all the images have been cropped to maximize the percentage of pixels occupied by the full face. The trained model is 98% accurate on classifying the test set. I get similar results if I select facial images at random from the internet and crop them to maximize the percent of pixels representing only the full face.

Answer (score 0):

The training set is very different from what you are giving as input to model using the randomly internet image.

The training set is composed from images that have no "noise", they are pure rappresentation of the fruit without extra items around. The image that you are trying to classify instead, has something around (in your case an hand).

So if you want that kind of classification to work you need a different dataset to train your model.

For reference look here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification
Look at the middle of the page at cat and dogs images for example, they are all inside a real context.

Look at the tecniques used in that doc about augmentation and other hints on how to make something like that usable.

Comment: Can't I do any pre-processing on the input image and make them like training set images and then give to model to predict.

Comment: instead of pre-processing the input image, make your training data to have different types of images, so that you can make a better model.